# How can I count the number of comments and likes that a post has in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

[posts table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcWGQ.png)

[comments table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbXFE.png)

[likes table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST1yM.png)

I have three tables and want to use 'left join' and 'group by' to get the total amount of likes and comments when fetching a list of posts. I tried

```
select posts.text, posts.id, count(comments.post_id) as comments, 
count(likes.post_id) as likes from posts
left join likes on posts.id = likes.post_id
left join comments on posts.id = comments.post_id
group by posts.id
```

But it gives a wrong result. How can I do it correctly?

Comment: I would suggest storing the like count in the post table

Comment: Also, explain what you are trying to accomplish.  One way to do that is give an example of the results you expect.  Why is the result you are getting wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might do the trick for you:

```
select post.id, count(distinct comments.id), count(distinct likes.id)
from post
left join comments on post.id = comments.post_id
left join likes on post.id = likes.post_id
group by post.id
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as answered (below the up/down votes).